# How can I represent the regular language ∑={a,b,c} with a regular expression in such a way that two characters 'b' cannot be next to each other?

Tags: regex, regex-group, regular-language, jflap

The alphabets of a regular language are ∑={a,b,c}

I need create regular expression for:

a.) Accepts strings that do not have two 'b' characters next to each other.
example: aabccbaaccb  <- allowed
aabccbaaccbb <- not allowed

b.) Accepts strings with at least one character 'a' between two characters 'b'.
example: babaaaaaab   <- allowed
babaaaaaabcb <- not allowed

Created regular expression need to be ready for that it can be tested with JFLAP.

[Here is what Regular Expression I have already try to create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQtEl.jpg)

Comment: From [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): "_**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question_"

Comment: It is confusion that in point (a) you say that `aabccbaaccb` is allowed, but then it is not allowed by (b). So in the end it is not allowed.

Comment: Sorry if I expressed it unclearly. I need to construct two different regular expressions. Sections A and B have different requirements for forming a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this would work:

```
^[ac]*(?:b$|bc*$|bc*a[ac]*)*$
```

In testing, it only matches strings where any pair of `b`s are separated by at least one `a`, just as the prompt describes.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. Can you tell if this means the same thing as what you just wrote?      ^(a|c)*(?:b$|bc*$|bc*a(a|c)*)*$

Comment: @HenrikEronen, yes, it looks equivalent

Answer (score 0):

For task A:

```
(a+c+ba+bc)*(b+!)
```

(For some odd reason JFLAP uses `!` to represent the empty string, i.e. ϵ)

For task B:

```
(a+c+bc*a)*(bc*+!)
```

Comment: Do you mean with these I can solve task 'a' or task 'b'. I mean I have two separate problems to solve.

Comment: The question mentioned "regular expression" in singular. You seem to be looking for two regular expressions. Also, the `regex` tag is maybe not what you intended, as that is a syntax with different symbols than you seem to use in the screenshot. See update of this answer. Not sure if you expect ϵ symbol for saying "don't consume any input". In regex syntax this is denoted with a `?` making a symbol optional.

Comment: Yes I have been looking for two regular expressions. Sorry for that, my expression in English is not so good.

Comment: OK, did you have a chance to look at the regular expressions I proposed?